# Custom allocator for fast std::wstring allocations

Tags: c++, performance, boost, allocator

Is there any open-source allocator (possibly in Boost) that can be used with `std::wstring` implementing a *fast* allocation pattern like the one showed in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/19/420038.aspx)?

Boost.Pool [doesn't seem well suited for this purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451585/using-vectorwstring-with-boost-pool-allocator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't (I searched for a couple of hours, once). If you don't care to release memory during usage, it is fairly simple to do yourself. If you want to release it dynamically, then it becomes a lot of work regarding free list management, LRU, etc.

Comment: Yes, I did several searches and found nothing.

Comment: It is kind of sad, but I guess it is not relevant enough to be of interest for the boost people.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek I think the problem is really relevant, but really hard to solve in a `one-size fits all`-style. I certainly would be glad for general, reusable arena allocators and have several places where I would like to use them.